# Why is configobj returning a list of strings without their values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, config, ini

I am trying to read an ini file into a nested dictionary (section->attribute->value), but when I try to use configobj to read it and use a for loop to print that object's values I just get a list of strings of the sections without any of their values when I want a dictionary with that string as the key and the values from the file as the keys' values.

`self._myConfigObj = configobj.ConfigObj(infile=myIniFile)`

The loop I am using to print its contents

```
for x in self._supervisorConfigObj:
print(x)
```

The output of that loop looks like

```
Section1
Section2
```

The structure of my ini file is just

```
[Section1]
Attribute1 = value
```

With multiple sections and values in each.

**Edit: Ok accessing a section manually and printing that `print(self._muConfigObj['Section1'])`shows the values so they are there and it's just a matter of accessing it incorrectly. **

Comment: So exactly how do you `"try to use configobj"`? You don't seem to show that bit. Please update your question with some relevant code.

Comment: It's just that one line where I create a ConfigObj object with my ini file as the infile and then looping and printing the elements of that just returns a list of strings instead of the key value pairs I want from the ini file

Comment: So, I think we need to see that loop.

Comment: I can guess what you've done.  You have a loop where you do `for k in cfg['Section1'}:` / `print(k)`, right?  Each section is a dictionary.  Iterating through a dictionary produces only the keys.  You keed `for k,v in cfg["Section1"}.items():`.

Comment: Are you using [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser)?